# Embedded document library views

Tags: development, document, library

I have used the embed app to link to a document library on a different web site within my collection. 
I have created views in the library for different teams
The library displays fine but goes to the default view
I'm looking for a snippet which would choose the right view

Comment: If you go to the edit settings of each view, at the very top it shows you (and let's you alter) the URL to that specific view.  Specify that URL in your embed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the URL of the list view and then put it in the embed code and you should get the required list view. For example:

```
<iframe src="{ListViewURL}" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Per my test, when using the snippet above to insert a list view, it allows you to see the list/library menu from the Embed web part in both SharePoint Server or SharePoint Online.

Comment: Hi thank for your help, the problem turned out to be an extra bit of code which was at the end of the URL, IsDlg=1, once I deleted all worked fine PDAA Pete